# Creating an overlapping vbar chart in Python, Bokeh

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I am a bit rusty in programming.  I was trying to code the Open Interest in an overlapping vbar column using Bokeh. But could not get to it. All I managed is a stacked bar. Since the X axis values are more I wanted to display both the X and Y axis as tool tip. How do I get to have similar kind of overlapping Column Chart. I am using the data from a Pandas DataFrame.

```
    df= option_chain('NIFTY', 'OPTIDX', date_='29OCT2020')
    df1= df[['Strike Price', 'CE OI', 'PE OI']]
    df1=df1.fillna(0)
    stacked_bar_df=df1
    cds_stacked_bar_df= ColumnDataSource(stacked_bar_df)
    stacked_bar_chart = figure(plot_width = 2400, plot_height=800, 
     x_axis_label = 
    "Strike Prices" , title= "Open Interest")
   
    stacked_bar_chart.vbar_stack(['PE OI', 'CE OI'],
    x = 'Strike Price',
    width = 30,
    source = cds_stacked_bar_df,
    color=("red","blue"))
  
    stacked_bar_chart.add_tools(HoverTool())
    show(stacked_bar_chart)
-----------------------------------
Update I got it by creating two glyphs but with differing width size.
    df= option_chain('NIFTY', 'OPTIDX', date_='29OCT2020')
    df['Strike Price'] = df['Strike Price'].astype('int64')   
    df1= df[['Strike Price','PE OI', 'CE OI']]

    df1=df1.fillna(0)

    x= df1['PE OI'].tolist()
    y= df1['Strike Price'].tolist()
    z= df1['CE OI'].tolist()


    plt = figure( plot_width=2000, plot_height=600 , title = "Open Interest")                      
                           
    plt.vbar(x = y, top = x, bottom=0, width=30,color= "red")
                        
    plt.vbar(x = y, top = z, bottom=0, width= 20,color= "blue")

    plt.add_tools(HoverTool())
    show(plt)
```

[Output I require](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCOVY.png)

Comment: Can you show us your code you have tried so far?

Comment: df= option_chain('NIFTY', 'OPTIDX', date_='29OCT2020')
df1= df[['Strike Price', 'CE OI', 'PE OI']]
df1=df1.fillna(0)
stacked_bar_df=df1
cds_stacked_bar_df= ColumnDataSource(stacked_bar_df)


stacked_bar_chart = figure(plot_width = 2400, plot_height=800, x_axis_label = "Strike Prices" , 
                          
                           title= "Open Interest")

stacked_bar_chart.vbar_stack(['PE OI', 'CE OI'],
x = 'Strike Price',
width = 30,
source = cds_stacked_bar_df,
color=("red","blue"))
stacked_bar_chart.add_tools(HoverTool())
show(stacked_bar_chart)

Comment: Edit the question and add code in there. So that views can go high.

Comment: Use `vbar` instead of `vbar_stack` and use its `width` attribute.

Comment: I got the output I want. I created two glyphs with different widths.

Comment: Thanks team for the support. Will be in touch to render the plot some more things smoothly